# How to use logstash-logger gem with lograge, Rails 5 API or Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logstash, rails-api

I tried to follow the both README files: at logrange gem and [logstash-logger](https://github.com/dwbutler/logstash-logger) gem without success.

The first try was with a simple Ruby file:

```
require 'logstash-logger'

logger = LogStashLogger.new(
  type: :tcp,
  host: 'abcdxxtr',
  port: 3332,
  verify_hostname: false
)
logger.debug message: 'hello-draft', foo: 'bar'
logger.info 'hello-draft => test'
```

When running from Terminal as `ruby logstash_logger.rb`, here is the errors I got:

```
E, [2018-08-14T14:43:37.848226 #11853] ERROR -- : [LogStashLogger::Device::TCP] SocketError - getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

When using with a Rails API app, it does not seem to send something either.

1. I added the following gems to the `Gemfile`:

`group :development do
  gem 'lograge',         '~> 0.10.0'
  gem 'logstash-event',  '~> 1.2'
  gem 'logstash-logger', '~> 0.26.1'
end`

2. Added the following lines to `config/environments/development.rb`:

   `config.lograge.enabled = true
   config.lograge.base_controller_class = 'ActionController::API'
   config.lograge.formatter = Lograge::Formatters::Logstash.new
   config.lograge.logger = LogStashLogger.new(uri: ENV['logstash_uri'])
   config.lograge.custom_options = lambda do |event|
   { name: "store-development" }
   end`

What's wrong with that ? I've already tried to use another syntax to initialize `LogStashLogger`:

```
config.lograge.logger = LogStashLogger.new(type: :tcp, host: ENV['logstash_host'], port: ENV['logstash_port'])
```

unfortunately, still no success.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar error in some rails projects and not in others, using a configuration like this:

```
type: :multi_delegator,
  outputs: [
    { type: :file, path: 'log/test.log' },
    { type: :udp, host: 'localhost', port: 5228 },
    { type: :io, io: io }
  ]
```

in the test environment to send the logs to multiple locations.

It turns out, this error

```
getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

is what you get when DNS can't be resolved. For me, the ones that didn't work were being run by Sidekiq, and changing from localhost to 127.0.0.1 solved the problem.

Comment: I think most of problems are related to Logstash stack network setting, e.g. firewall, opened.closed ports, etc. DevOps folks have not much intention to dig deeper with issues like that.

Comment: Could be, although it's not obvious to me how the network settings could be different for processes on the same box, using the same ports (although not at the same time, obviously)